# $2$-dimensional Hyperbolic space with fundamental group ${\bf Z}$ and constant curvature $-1$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, curvature, fundamental-groups

$$ d\rho^2 + \cosh^2\rho\ d\theta^2$$

Only one ? Is there any other example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have essentially two choices: either the quotient of the hyperbolic plane by (the cyclic group generated by) a hyperbolic isometry or the quotient of the hyperbolic plane by (the cyclic group generated by) a parabolic isometry.

Comment: I need more details

Comment: Actually, the 1st choice is a continuum if choices.

Comment: More detail? Well, take a hyperbolic isometry, say $x\rightarrow 2x$. A Fundamental Domain in the upper half plane is given by $1\le y\le 2$, in the Quotient the boundary Lines are identified, so you get a cylinder and you can figure out how to describe the hyperbolic metric in cylindrical coordinates.